# How to parse yaml conditional fields in rust?

Tags: rust, yaml, serde

In the yaml files below:

```yaml
// 1. book yaml
kind: book
title: Someone's life

publisher: someone
published_at: 2023-02-24T09:31:00Z+09:00
```

```yaml
// 2. movie yaml
kind: movie
title: Someone's life

director: someone else
```

`kind` is key for recognizing that yaml is what for. If kind is `book`, this matter have `publisher` and `published_at`. however, if kind is `movie`, this matter doesn't have `publisher` but `director`.

In my short thought, for parsing it, i have to make general parse struct.
ex:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct General {
  kind: String,
  title: String,
}
```

parse one time using General struct, then get parsed general's kind and re-parse with another struct.
ex:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Book {
  kind: String,
  title: String,
  publisher: String,
  published_at: String,
}
```

Above scenario can be works, but i have to parse two time. But, Is this efficient?

Comment: If you want to parse everything in a single go you could declare `publisher`, `published_at` and `director` as `Optional<String>`, all in a single struct. You could handle the rest in code, so if `kind` is book then you're going to have `director = None`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deserialize in Rust (using serde) optional json parameter that can be either string or string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62031397/how-to-deserialize-in-rust-using-serde-optional-json-parameter-that-can-be-eit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [serde's tag attribute](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#tag) for this. [Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c7e6fe36368b35f4be3b4cd95b8069ec)

```
use serde::Deserialize;
use serde_yaml; // 0.8.26

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag="kind", rename_all="lowercase")]
enum Media {
    Book(Book),
    Movie(Movie),
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Book {
    title: String,
    publisher: String,
    published_at: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Movie {
    title: String,
    director: String,
}

fn main() {
    let book: Media = serde_yaml::from_str("kind: book
title: Someone's life

publisher: someone
published_at: 2023-02-24T09:31:00Z+09:00").unwrap();

    let movie: Media = serde_yaml::from_str("kind: movie
title: Someone's life

director: someone else").unwrap();

    println!("{book:?}");
    println!("{movie:?}");

}
```

Comment: awesome. actually perfect solution for me. thank you. i will see serde’s doc more. thank you